# Find all elements except for those with certain class with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using the [simple_html_dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and I want to fetch data from html code that looks like this:

```
<pre class="root">
     <span class="B bgB"></span>
     <span class="B bgB"></span>
     <span class="B bgB"></span>
     <span class="B bgB"></span>
     <span class="W"></span>
     <span class="Y DH"> </span>
     <span class="Y DH">Some text</span>
</pre>
```

etc..

But I only want to get the content from the ones *without* the bgB class. So far I have this code:

```
$elements = $html->find('pre.root span[class!=bgB]');
```

But all spans are fetched and later printed, not only the ones without the bgB class. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try with $elements = $html->find('pre.root span[class!=B]');

Comment: The only way to do that with simple_html_dom parser is to find all spans then check their class value `if (strpos($span->class,'bgB') === false) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be done with simple but if you switch to [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/?source=directory) you can use the css `:not` pseudo:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$elements = $html->find('pre.root span:not(.bgB)');
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to exclude two classes? for example bgB and bgY.

Comment: You should be able to chain those `:not`s: `span:not(.bgB):not(.bgY)`

Comment: @pguardiario thanks for the answer. How we can retrieve a div value which has more than 1 class or id name? using simple html dom

Comment: @guna, more than one id wouldn't make sense, and more than one class with simple you would have to do all or nothing for example `div[class="foo bar"]`